# Solving a differential equation involving drag force and acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag

I've undertaken a project which requires me to find a function for the horizontal velocity, in terms of time. For context, I'm studying the movement of a cannonball against air resistance and I need to find the initial i.e. launch horizontal velocity.

The formula for air resistance (drag force) involves a lot of annoying constants, so I'll just compress these into a single constant $k$. The formula for the drag force then looks like $F = kv^2$.

I set up a differential equation for the acceleration experienced by the cannonball:

$$m\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dt} = - kv^2$$

I know the values of $m$ and $k$; I also know that at time $507.1$, the horizontal velocity = $7351 \mathrm{ms}^{-1}$.

I tried solving this to get something like $$v = \frac{1}{t+c}\frac{m}{k},$$ where $c$ is a constant of integration and $t$ is the time. This makes no sense when I plug in $t = 0$: I get something like $17\, \mathrm{ms}^{-1}$, which is impossible because the cannonball should be moving the fastest just after it is launched.

I'm completely beat and would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: On solving i got $-1/v=(-kt/m)+c$

Comment: 7km/s?  I hope this is a toy problem, because that drag equation doesn't work at hypersonic velocities.

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting confusion you've ran into here. You need to bring in gravity. Don't you think that the gravitational pull on the object will affect its speed as well?

Have you learned about vector equations yet? ${\bf F} = m {\bf a}$ is a vector equation. If your canonball motion is in the plane, with ${\bf E}_y$ pointing up, the equations are:

$k v^2 (-\frac{{\bf v}}{v}) + mg (-{\bf E}_y) = m \frac{d {\bf v}}{d t} = m(\frac{d v_x}{dt}{\bf E}_x + \frac{d v_y}{dt} {\bf E}_y)$.

Your goal then is to solve for $v_x(t)$ and $v_y(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation neglects the force of gravity. Also, your equation will not tell you anything about the path the object takes. You need to separate this into components -- one differential equation for the $x$ motion, and the other for the $y$ motion.

Everything you need is here: [http://www.physics.udel.edu/~szalewic/teach/419/cm08ln_quad-drag.pdf](http://www.physics.udel.edu/%7Eszalewic/teach/419/cm08ln_quad-drag.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the notes, they were exactly what I needed. How would I go about solving the coupled equations numerically, though - Euler's method?

Answer (score 0):

your differential equation has the solution

$$v(t)=\frac{m\,v_0}{m-k\,v_0\,t}$$

with
$v(t_e)=v_e~$ you can obtain the the constant $~v_0$

$$v_0=\frac{m\,v_e}{m+k\,v_e\,t_e}$$